# Android Notification vibrates with NotifiationChannel.enableVibration(false)

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo, notification-channel

With API 26 (Android 8.0) we need to define a [NotificationChannel](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ManageChannels) for each Notification. Each channel has its own settings of disruptions (e.g. vibration, light, sound).

*Problem:*
When I disable vibration for this channel and deploy this on a Android 8.0  (security update September 2017) phone (Nexus 5X), **the notification triggers vibration anyway** and is opened automatically (pop-in) which I did not set and want to disable.

1. I register a NotificationChannel in my MainActivity:

   ```
   // Register NotificationChannels needed for API 26+ to display notification messages
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
       NotificationChannel runningChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_RUNNING,
               getString(R.string.notification_channel_name_running), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
       runningChannel.enableLights(false);
       runningChannel.enableVibration(false);
       mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(runningChannel);
   }
   ```
2. I set the NotificationChannel for the Notification:

   ```
   notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
               .setContentIntent(onClickPendingIntent)
               .setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_RUNNING)
               .setOngoing(true)
               .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
               .setAutoCancel(false)
               .build();
   ```

**Update (security update 5th October 2017)**

Now everything works as expected without workaround so I can choose targetSDK 26 (before, I used 25 to avoid this false behavior). For the case when other releases have a similar bug of other phones did not yet receive the newest update, I marked the workaround below as accepted answer.

Comment: try changing importance level?NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @ArnavM. However, it does not change the behaviour (still vibrates and pops up the notification). Can you explain why you think that this should have made any difference?

Comment: a related point to take care off not to make an incorrect implementation by using both enableVibration() and setVibrationPattern() take look here: https://proandroiddev.com/oreo-notification-feature-a-critical-issue-that-could-restart-your-android-phone-ca122fa4d9cb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
runningchannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0});
```

Yes, it's weird

Comment: Thanks @Piotr, I will check it out as soon as there is time and mark your answer as correct when it works. Cheers!

Comment: My Nexus 5X got a system update "October 5th, 2017". After this update I do not get the false behavior mentioned in the question. Thus, I did not need to use your workaround but it seems legit so I mark it as the correct aswer others might not yet receive the newest Android 8 update or get this false behavior in future releases. Thanks, mate!

Comment: This worked for me. When modifying notification channels, always uninstall and install the app.

Comment: @hb0 I want to mention that there is an issue if you make an incorrect implementation take a look at this post https://proandroiddev.com/oreo-notification-feature-a-critical-issue-that-could-restart-your-android-phone-ca122fa4d9cb

Comment: Thanks for your answer, uninstalling and installing the app worked for me.

Comment: @krisDrOid thanks I was wondering why there are no changes when I set the vibration until I found your comment and reinstalled the app. Absolute saviour